# ssl error on asio server on https connect

Tags: c++, server, openssl, boost-asio, handshake

I took the SimpleWebServer from Eidheim on gitlab (https://gitlab.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server) and I wanted to make that https server to also process http and special plain socket queries. They all work, but when stress testing it, https has quite some errors, that I didn't see before my changes. Btw: It is always the same query and as a single query, it works fine. EDIT: The server uses a selfsigned certificate.

With about 3 https queries per second (which is not much) I occasionally get the following errors:

- sslv3 alert certificate unknown
- crash in: SSL_accept (openssl/ssl.h) -> libssl-1_1.dll -> libcrypto-1_1.dll
- C:\curl\src\curl.exe -k https://192.168.0.228:3012/status
  curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 192.168.0.228:3012

I am testing with curl in a batch loop with -k for insecure connection:

```
:START
C:\curl\src\curl.exe -k https://192.168.0.228:3012/status
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
goto START
```

I changed the handshake and accept of the server. I read exactly one byte of the stream:
-> determine if it is a signal byte from a socket query
-> else, if the firstbyte is not equal to 0x16 (TLS handshake starts with 0x16, without it it is just an http query)
-> else it is supposed to be an https query

Only for https I read the rest of the handshake data and continue with async_handshake.
Originally async_handshake read the handshake data on its own instead of me providing the sslbuffer to it and I fear that that causes the instability.

EDIT: To see the ssl handshake, that troubles me, skip to //-----------------------MY THIRD CHANGE

```
auto connection = create_connection(*io_service, context);

acceptor->async_accept(connection->socket->lowest_layer(), [this, connection](const error_code &ec) {
auto lock = connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
if(!lock)
    return;

if(ec != error::operation_aborted)
    this->accept();

auto session = std::make_shared<Session>(config.max_request_streambuf_size, connection);

if(!ec) {
    asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
    error_code ec;
    session->connection->socket->lowest_layer().set_option(option, ec);
//-----------------------MY FIRST CHANGE - read first byte
    //read some bytes, needed before the handshake
    const unsigned int bytesToRead = 1;
    int size_of_the_data = 100;
    std::vector<unsigned char> _raw_buffer(size_of_the_data);
    asio::mutable_buffers_1 sslBuffer(asio::buffer(_raw_buffer, size_of_the_data));

    asio::async_read(session->connection->socket->next_layer(), boost::asio::buffer(sslBuffer, bytesToRead), asio::transfer_exactly(bytesToRead), [this, sslBuffer, bytesToRead, session](const error_code& ecRead, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/){

    //Get the read data from the buffer in a readable form
    unsigned char * firstByte = asio::buffer_cast<unsigned char*>(sslBuffer);

//-----------------------MY SECOND CHANGE - use first byte to determine if https, http or socket
    if (SocketQuery::CheckForSocketQuery(firstByte[0])) {
        session->connection->cancel_timeout();
        auto lock = session->connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
        if (!lock)
        return;
        session->isHttps = false;
        this->read_socket(session, firstByte[0]);
    }
    else if (!SocketQuery::is_client_TLS_handshake(firstByte))
    {
        session->connection->cancel_timeout();
        auto lock = session->connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
        if (!lock)
        return;
        session->isHttps = false;
        this->read_http(session, firstByte[0]);
    }
//-----------------------MY THIRD CHANGE - read the handshake manually and pass it to async_handshake
    else
    {
        try
        {
            //read handshake, 4000 Bytes should be way more than any handshake needs (which is something between 200 and 400 bytes usually)
            session->connection->socket->next_layer().async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(sslBuffer + bytesToRead, 4000), [this, sslBuffer, bytesToRead, session](const error_code& ecReadHandshake, std::size_t bytesOfHandshake) {
                try
                {
                    bytesOfHandshake += bytesToRead;
                    session->connection->set_timeout(config.timeout_request);

                    //Use overload of async_handshake with buffer as second parameter
                    //Note that the async callback lambda is expected to take the buffer and buffer size as you see below
                    session->connection->socket->async_handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::server, asio::buffer(sslBuffer, bytesOfHandshake), [this, sslBuffer, session](const error_code& ecHttps, std::size_t bufferSize) {
                        try
                        {
                            session->connection->cancel_timeout();
                            auto lock = session->connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
                            if (!lock)
                                return;

                            if (!ecHttps)
                            {
                                this->read(session);
                            }
                            else if (this->on_error)
                            {
                                this->on_error(session->request, ecHttps);
                                wxLogMessage("server error: " + wxString(ecHttps.message()));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                wxLogMessage("server handshake error: " + wxString(ecHttps.message()));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (const std::exception& e)
                        {
                            wxLogMessage("cought server handshake o3 error: " + wxString(e.what()));
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (const std::exception& e)
                {
                    wxLogMessage("cought server handshake o2 error: " + wxString(e.what()));
                }
            });
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            wxLogMessage("cought server handshake o1 error: " + wxString(e.what()));
        }
    }
    });
}
else if(this->on_error)
    this->on_error(session->request, ec);
      
});
```

I tried to stop the server crashing uncontrolled with the try/catches for https, but the crash happens deeper into the ssl accept and I am unable to stop my server crashing so far.
I read before, that it is possible, that a async_read tries to read from the socket, before all the actual data is on it. Maybe I am wrong to think it would be safe to try and read 4000 Bytes from the socket for the handshake. Any idea how to improve that?

EDIT: I just found out: A handshake data set can be greater than 4000 Bytes, if the certificate is rather long. So another question is: How is the handshake data devided from the https header data? Is there also a double newline?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I really can't tell if this is the best sollution, but it certainly is a better one. I couldn't find an answer to all my questions, so if anyone else still wants to explain some of the errors, Im all ears.

I couldn't find the separator between ssl and header, so I tried the same separator which works for header and body separation.
For the ssl data, I now use asio::async_read_until and I read until double endline "\r\n\r\n".
After this change, the crashes for https went down drastically.

```
auto connection = create_connection(*io_service, context);

acceptor->async_accept(connection->socket->lowest_layer(), [this, connection](const error_code &ec) {
auto lock = connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
if(!lock)
    return;

if(ec != error::operation_aborted)
    this->accept();

auto session = std::make_shared<Session>(config.max_request_streambuf_size, connection);

if(!ec) {
    asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
    error_code ec;
    session->connection->socket->lowest_layer().set_option(option, ec);

    //read some bytes, needed before the handshake
    const unsigned int bytesToRead = 1;
    int size_of_the_data = 100;

    std::shared_ptr<asio::streambuf> streambuf = std::make_shared<asio::streambuf>();

    asio::async_read(session->connection->socket->next_layer(), *streambuf, asio::transfer_exactly(bytesToRead), [this, streambuf, bytesToRead, session](const error_code& ecRead, std::size_t bytes_transferred) mutable {

    //Get the read data from the buffer in a readable form
    const std::vector<unsigned char> vectorBuffer = { asio::buffers_begin(streambuf->data()), asio::buffers_end(streambuf->data()) };


    if (SocketQuery::CheckForSocketQuery(vectorBuffer.at(0))) {
        session->connection->cancel_timeout();
        auto lock = session->connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
        if (!lock)
        return;
        session->isHttps = false;
        this->read_socket(session, vectorBuffer.at(0));
    }
    else if (!SocketQuery::is_client_TLS_handshake(vectorBuffer.at(0)))
    {
        session->connection->cancel_timeout();
        auto lock = session->connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
        if (!lock)
        return;
        session->isHttps = false;
        this->read_http(session, vectorBuffer.at(0));
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            auto readUntil = "\r\n\r\n";
            asio::async_read_until(*session->connection->socket, *streambuf, readUntil, [this, streambuf, bytesToRead, session](const error_code&ecReadHandshake, std::size_t bytesOfHandshake) mutable {
                try
                {
                const std::vector<unsigned char> vectorBuf = { asio::buffers_begin(streambuf->data()), asio::buffers_end(streambuf->data()) };

                bytesOfHandshake += bytesToRead;
                session->connection->set_timeout(config.timeout_request);

                //Use overload of async_handshake with buffer as second parameter
                //Note that the async callback lambda is expected to take the buffer and buffer size as you see below
                session->connection->socket->async_handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::server, asio::buffer(vectorBuf, bytesOfHandshake), [this,session](const error_code& ecHttps, std::size_t bufferSize) mutable {
                try
                {
                    session->connection->cancel_timeout();
                    auto lock = session->connection->handler_runner->continue_lock();
                    if (!lock)
                        return;

                    if (!ecHttps)
                    {
                        this->read(session);
                    }
                    else if (this->on_error)
                    {
                        this->on_error(session->request, ecHttps);
                        wxLogMessage("server error: " + wxString(ecHttps.message()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wxLogMessage("server handshake error: " + wxString(ecHttps.message()));
                    }
                }
                catch (const std::exception& e)
                {
                    wxLogMessage("cought server handshake o3 error: " + wxString(e.what()));
                }
                });
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e)
            {
                wxLogMessage("cought server handshake o2 error: " + wxString(e.what()));
            }
        });
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            wxLogMessage("cought server handshake o1 error: " + wxString(e.what()));
        }
    }
    });
}
else if(this->on_error)
    this->on_error(session->request, ec);
      
});
```

EDIT: I have now found a Byte by Byte explanation and thus there is a better way to read the handshake. (I might change the code if I run into problems again)
https://tls.ulfheim.net/